# Equilibrium concentration of point defects in solids at sufficiently elevated temperature

Tags: material-science

Equilibrium concentration of point defects in solids is defined as $\chi=\exp(\frac{\Delta s}{k_B})\exp(\frac{-\Delta h}{k_BT})$. At high temperatures, may be even higher than melting temperature of the solid, does the entropy become undefined meaning there will be no equilibrium concentration for point defects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, the equation can yield a result at any temperature. But, since the concept of point defect makes sense only in a crystal, in a liquid the calculation yields a number with no meaning. Like applying the formula to T < 0.

Also, the equilibrium concentration is not "defined" by your equation.